# Is it really necessary to restrict user to input password with only certain character

Tags: forms, validation

I have seen many websites with their own rule of password validation. someone says don't input *&^%, few people says it should be between 8-12 character, etc. Is it really necessary?

I mean the password field should not be validated at all! what if I have 3 character password in my mind and it's impossible to guess!

Or else there should be a standard password validation so that user mindset will be constant for all website rather have to think every time before registering at a new website about their password rules.

Comment: Pretty sure this has been answered on either the UI site or Security, depending on what angle you're asking the question from. This doesn't seem to be much of a programming question right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good standard practice to require passwords of multiple character types. The longer and more complex a password is the harder it will be for a script to crack it. A three character password can take a matter of seconds to minutes to crack as where one that is eight to twelve characters (i.e. - letters, numbers, and special characters) can take upwards of years to crack. In the end it is up to you how secure you want your content to be.